# android java context explanation

Tags: java, android, function, android-context

I have the following question:

I have to use the following function from BT printer SDK:

```
    StarIOPort port = null;
    byte[] texttoprint = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40, 0x1b,0x74,0x0D,(byte) 0x91,(byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95,(byte) 0x96,(byte) 0x97,(byte) 0x98,(byte) 0x99,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A};


    try 
    {
        port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName, portSettings, 10000, context);
        port.writePort(textToPrint, 0, textToPrint.length);
        port.writePort(new byte[] {0x0a}, 0, 1);
    }
    catch (StarIOPortException e)
    {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
        alert.setTitle("Failure");
        alert.setMessage("Failed to connect to printer");
        alert.show();
    }
```

I have understand everything except of context.

The manufacturer mention that

```
 * @param context - Activity for displaying messages to the user
```

How can I use the above function because in the way I use it I do not receive any error neither any alert message.

Comment: Seems You might observe alert only if StarIOPortException occurred.

Comment: You are write but I do not receive any alert enen in exception

Comment: do you get exception (not sure what "enen" stands for)? if you got exception, post the stack trace

Comment: exception usually is an abnormal/error situation. So, if You don't receive an exception that usually means that code works without error. If You need to observe alert - change code or produce error situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is your Activity.

```
private Context context;
context = this;
```

Here is a complete sample activity.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import <my_star_io_library>;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity 
{
    private Context context;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Save context
        context = this;

        StarIOPort port = null; 
        byte[] texttoprint = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40, 0x1b,0x74,0x0D,(byte) 0x91,(byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95,(byte) 0x96,(byte) 0x97,(byte) 0x98,(byte) 0x99,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A}; 

        try  
        { 
            port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName, portSettings, 10000, context); 
            port.writePort(textToPrint, 0, textToPrint.length); 
            port.writePort(new byte[] {0x0a}, 0, 1); 
        } 
        catch (StarIOPortException e) 
        { 
            Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null); 
            AlertDialog alert = dialog.create(); 
            alert.setTitle("Failure"); 
            alert.setMessage("Failed to connect to printer"); 
            alert.show(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If i want to use the above function inside a phonegap plugin how will I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To display Alert (or any other UI component) you need Activity context, that's right. If you do not have any Activity running at the moment, you can't display Alert.

But you can display Toast, using static method of class [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html):

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration);
```

passing to it Application Context as first parameter.

Application context is always available while your app is running, even if there are no UI running at the moment. You can get it by calling **getApplicationContext()** method from your context. If you don't have any context at all, you can always use YourAppClass (*public class YourAppClass extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)*), defined in your manifest under  xml tag.
Most common practice is to make *YourAppClass* a singleton, and it always be available at any point of code within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Context is a class related with an Activity,that you use when you have to show and AlertDialog, Toast, get system services... It is related with the arquitecture MVC,which is a bit longer to explain. About using it, there are two ways. One is explained by droidhot and another way is, for example, MainActivity.this, if you are using the AlertDialog in the Main Activity (MainActivity.java file), so the Main Activity will be the one that launches the Alert Dialog. If it is launched from another class which is not an Activity, you have to put the context as a parameter (for example, new Class(MainActivity.this)) and inside the class,it would be, for example, public class( Context context) ant the parameter context is the one you have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is subclass of Context so if you printing code is part of your Activity class, then simply provide `this` as required context to fulfill SDK requirements:

```
port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName, portSettings, 10000, this);
```

and later

```
Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted answer here:
[Android Phonegap Plugin different result on virtual and real device (Looper.prepare() ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010115/android-phonegap-plugin-different-result-on-virtual-and-real-device-looper-prep/12407878#12407878)

I had the same problem which appeared on some devices. Successfully one smart boy, Toby, helped me. So, solution is the next:
- before you call any StarIOPort's methods you have to check if looper exist:

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
    Looper.prepare();
}
```

in your case it's will looks like this:

```
 try 
 {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
        Looper.prepare();
    }
    port = StarIOPort.getPort("BT:", "mini", 10000, null);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    port.writePort(texttoprint, 0, texttoprint.length);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    resultType = "success";
 }
 catch (StarIOPortException e)
 {
     resultType = "error";
 }
```

One more advise:
instead

```
port = StarIOPort.getPort("BT:", "mini", 10000, null);
```

use just

```
port = StarIOPort.getPort("BT:", "mini", 10000);
```

in plugin you will not use Context

Good luck.